# Is there a way to pay via the Facebook Marketing API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

For the moment the only way to run ads is this link, because all the process can be made via the API, but not the delivering process via the payment?

https://www.facebook.com/ads/manager/account_settings/account_billing

Is there any way to make a payment to facebook ads through my platform?
I'm working with php sdk